# Стратегия кеширования страниц

Tags: кэширование

Я мало разбираюсь в ngnix кешировании. Сейчас ,как я понял,  прокси настроен так, что не пропускает заголовки if_modified ,в том числе для динамических страниц. Отдача ответа 304 Not modified, как я понимаю, осуществляется следующим образом : ngnix запрашивает страницу, сверяет длину страницы с длиной страницы из предыдущей отдачи и соответственно отдает нужный ответ. Вроде бы неплохо - прокси взял на себя всю работу по кешированию. Однако есть вопросы. Я пытаюсь разработать высоконагруженный сайт. И такая стратегия кеширования не кажется оптимальной. Фактически каждый раз движку сайта приходится формировать целую страницу, чтобы сверить кеш. Понятно, что можно  легко и быстро  проверить актуальность страницы с помощью легковесного скрипта перед началом формирования страницы. Это сэкономить время и ресурсы сервера. Для высоконагруженного сайта  c динамическими страницами с часто меняющейся информацией это очень актуально. Правильно ли я рассуждаю ,что посоветуете и что мне сделать, чтобы  все же запросы if-Modifed прорывались через прокси?

Answer (score 0):

В первую очередь нужно отключить no-cache режим кеширования в php установив опцию [session.cache_limiter = ''](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cache-limiter).

1. При генерации страницы сохраняйте время последнего изменения контента где-нибудь в key-value базе (например в Редисе или Мемкэше) и отдавайте заголовоки ответа [Last-Modified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Last-Modified) и [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching#the_cache-control_header)
2. При получении заголовка ответа клиент (браузер или прокси) будут сохранять полученную дату и в последующем делать запрос с заголовком If-Modified установленным в значение полученной ранее от вас даты Last-Modified.
3. Получив такой запрос вы извлекаете дату из key-value БД и сверяете. Если они у вас разные, то действуете в соответствии с п.1, а если одинаковые отдаете статус 304 Not Modified.
4. при обновлении контента сохраняете новую дату в key-value БД